# Reformulating problem into form of Ising Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-spin, hamiltonian, mathematics, ising-model, optimization

The Ising Hamiltonian has the following form:

$$H= -\sum_{j<k}J_{j,j+1}\sigma_j\sigma_{j+1}-\sum_{j} h_j\sigma_j + \varepsilon,$$

Where $\sigma$ are the spins that take values of $\pm$ 1

I have a problem which has the form:

$$ \max \qquad \sum^{n}_{i}v_{i}x_{i} - \lambda\left(\sum_{i}^{n} w_{i}x_{i} - K\right)^{2},$$

where x_{i} is binary. I make a subsition to rewrite this using \sigma_{i}. The problem is that at  some point during the derivation I arrive with a term of the form:

$$-\frac{\lambda}{4}(\sum_{i}\sum_{j \neq i} w_{i}w_{j} \sigma_{i}\sigma_{j})$$.

This term contains all the cross products between all the spins. I need to rewrite this into a form which contains only nearest neighbours and also term that considers all other interactions but with only a single $\sigma$ in the equation so that it still meets the form of the Ising Hamiltonian. Is this possible and what steps would I take to do this?

Comment: It depends on the system you want to describe. Usually we assume that the interaction of spins that are not nearest neighbors is neglected, we speak of local interactions. This is a valid approximation for some systems, it might or might not be valid in your case.

Comment: Thanks! So in this case the original problem is just the knapsack problem in a QUBO form. How would I know that's its ok to ignore nonlocal interactions for a system.

Comment: To what corresponds the term proportional to $\lambda$? Are you trying to fix the total volume?

Comment: Here $\lambda$ is just a Lagrange multiplier. It's just a coefficient that scales the penalty (constraint) term so that the solution obtained does not violate the constraint whilst also still being optimal.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're optimising over all the possible $x\in\{\pm1\}^n$ with fixed $v,w,K,\lambda$?

Comment: Hey sorry for the late response and yes that is correct

Answer (score 0):

you can add an auxillary spin, say $\sigma_{n+1}$ which takes 1. then the single $\sigma$ can be treat as the coupling between it and this auxillary spin.

i also suggest you check again the correctness of the QUBO formulation of the Knapsack problem. in the current one it also penalises the case when the knapsack is not full.